# Having a struct as an attribute of a core data entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my core data model, I have an entity for which its attribute is a struct. Here's the struct

```
struct Range: NSCoding {
    let minValue: Int
    let maxValue: Int

/* implementations of
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) 
   and
     func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
*/
}
```

For brevity sake, let's imagine an entity like so:

```
 Question
    -title: String
    -range: Range
```

I know that the range attribute needs to be a Transformable in the data model.

When trying to assign Range as the class of the transformable, I get the `Property cannot be marked @NSManaged because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C` error

What is the correct setup?

More specifically, what's the correct values for the following attributes in the Xcode editor?

- Value Tranformer
- Custom Class (I tried to set it as Range)
- Module (currently set to 'current module')

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would save `minValue` and `maxValue` as `Int32` in the entity

```
@NSManaged var minValue: Int32
@NSManaged var maxValue: Int32
```

use a simple version if the struct (since `NSCoding` doesn't support structs anyway)

```
struct Range {
    let min: Int
    let max: Int
}
```

and a computed property in the `NSManagedObject` (sub)class to map both attributes to a `Range` object

```
var range : Range {
    get { return Range(min: Int(minValue), max: Int(maxValue)) }
    set {
        minValue = Int32(newValue.min)
        maxValue = Int32(newValue.max)
    }
}
```

---

or forget the struct and use a real `Range`

```
var range : Range<Int> {
    get { return Range<Int>(uncheckedBounds: (Int(minValue), Int(maxValue))) }
    set {
        minValue = Int32(newValue.lowerBound)
        maxValue = Int32(newValue.upperBound)
    }
}
```

Consider that `Range<T>` uses the half-open type: `0..<3` contains `0`, `1` and `2`

---

**Edit**

If the range is supposed to be optional then you could identify a valid range if `maxValue` > `minValue` for example

```
var range : Range<Int>? {
    get {
        guard maxValue > minValue else { return nil }
        return Range<Int>(uncheckedBounds: (Int(minValue), Int(maxValue))) }
    set {
        if let value = newValue {
            minValue = Int32(value.lowerBound)
            maxValue = Int32(value.upperBound)
        }  else {
            minValue = 0
            maxValue = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In my model, the range is optional, and I would like to make sure that if I have a range, it contains both min and max value. My temporary solution is to have a Range entity for that effect. If Range was a class, would it make things easier?

Comment: I added a suggestion for an optional computed property `range`.

Comment: I'll keep your solution in mind, but I feel there's a better way to store a struct in a core data entity.

Comment: Using `Transformable` for Core Data compliant value types is unnecessarily expensive.